# How do I add a constant column value during data transfer from CSV to SQL?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, csv

I am reading in CSV file and translating it to an SQL Table. The kicker is that one of the columns in the table is of data type ID that needs to be set to a constant (in this case 2).  I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Look into the [derived column transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx). Your formula will just be a constant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a [Derived Column Transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx) in which you'll create a new output column and set its value to 2. You can then use that column when outputting to SQL.